# can layout for a view for a specific action in controller can be changed in yii

Tags: layout, yii

I need to know can we have a different layout for a specific action in controller

**for controller/create i dont want the navigation bar appear  just can their be a form with no navigation bar**

but for the same controllers with different action should have the navigation bar .

what i know is if am not wrong we can have customised layout designed  and specify it in the controller if i wrong please let me know.

but i need to design different layout for specific action in controller

cAN I ACHIEVE SO if so Please guide me

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can do.

You have to declare layout in your controller as a class variable.

```
public $layout='column2';
```

Then in your action function, you can change the layout with use of below code.

```
public function actionFUNCTION()
{
$this->layout='column1'; // layout without nav bar.
$this->render('VIEW_PATH');
}
```

Comment: sorry for the late response by default gii provide public $layout='//layouts/column2'; in the controller file  .... i did witer this $this->layout='column1'; in controoler create yet nav bar appears  i did this too $this->layout='//layouts/column1'; not works

Comment: You can echo the layout in controller to check. Did you clear asset folder after the changes done?

Comment: i din get you why do i have to clear the asset folder?Will it not effect the  layout of other  files?

Comment: no. Asset folders having cache files. Asset means root -> assets. Not your modules -> assests

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to render your view without any layout.

```
$this->renderPartial();
```

Comment: sorry for delay to respond i was looking for a view you specified. finally i got it thanx :) this works pretty well i can add my css to it